# Can I autoload data, save from a comma delimited file, Excel, etc

Tags: trello, import

One solution was to use Trello for a Project Risk board, to show risks and mitigations. We use SharePoint for our Risk Register, but want to feed it into Trello. Didn't see the API to do that.

Is there a way to auto feed the data?

Comment: Have you looked at libraries that use Trello's API? `node-trello` in Node.js, and there are Python-based libraries as well. There are no ready and publicly available command-line apps that I know of, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [Trello Api documentation here](https://trello.com/docs/).

You will have to build a custom sharepoint solution to do a direct export from a Sharepoint List to whatever form you'd like them to appear in on Trello.

Comment: True, but it doesn't have to be a SharePoint solution. Another solution using the Trello API that is also able to retrieve the data from SharePoint might do the trick as well. Personally, I'm using the ```client.js``` library to interact with the Trello API from a normal HTML page.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't have to be a SharePoint solution, but it would make things a little easier than, for example, extracting data from the database or html scraping. There are some handy triggers that can be utilized like ItemAdded, ItemUpdated and ItemDeleted events that you can hook up to in a SharePoint solution. You could write your own, but it will probably cost a little more effort than using the existing infrastructure.